# Moving div moving whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Place a few 'Moving' divs in my blog, but it moving my whole page, scrolling up & down (like the table cell)

How to stop 'Moving' divs, moving the page?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    
function moveDown() {
    $('.Fly').animate({'marginTop' : "+=100px"}, 1000,moveUp)
}

function moveUp(){
    $('.Fly').animate({'marginTop' : "-=100px"}, 1000,moveDown)
}    
 moveUp(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width='500' style="border: 1px solid #000;">
<tr>
<th>
      
<div Class="Fly" style="position:relative; left: 280px; top: -580px;"></div> 
<div id="Superman"></div>   
         
<style>   
#Superman { background: url(http://www.comixoasis.com/v/vspfiles/templates/runner/images/homepage/Superman.png) no-repeat; width:250px; height:300px; background-size: 100%;       
}  
</style>
    
</th>      
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Comment: We have an [inline jsfiddle](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) since 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [absolute position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) on the `div` you are moving.

http://jsfiddle.net/re43q0z1/

So, change your HTML to:

```
<div Class="Fly" style="position:absolute; left: 280px; top: 80px; height: 300px; width: 300px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

There is no need to have an extra div for the image. Also you will need to change the needed width and height, or just embed the image. Also, styling should ideally be done using a style sheet.

And your Javascript only needs a small change to select the correct div: `$('.Fly')`.

As well as you need to change the selector for setting the background image from `#Superman` to `.Fly`.

Comment: position:absolute; the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the height for the Page too i.e.,height of table cell fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    
function moveDown() {
    $('.Fly').animate({'marginTop' : "+=100px"}, 1000,moveUp)
}

function moveUp(){
    $('.Fly').animate({'marginTop' : "-=100px"}, 1000,moveDown)
}    
 moveUp(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width='500' height='320' style="border: 1px solid #000;position:absolute;">
<tr>
<th>
      
 
<div id="Superman" Class="Fly"></div>   
         
<style>   
#Superman { background: url(http://www.comixoasis.com/v/vspfiles/templates/runner/images/homepage/Superman.png) no-repeat; width:250px; height:300px; background-size: 100%;       
}  
</style>
    
</th>      
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    
function moveDown() {
    $('#Superman').animate({'top' : "+=100px"}, 1000,moveUp)
}

function moveUp(){
    $('#Superman').animate({'top' : "-=100px"}, 1000,moveDown)
}    
 moveUp(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width='500' style="border: 1px solid #000;">
<tr>
<th>
      
<div Class="Fly" style="position:relative; left: 280px; top: -580px; height:300px;"></div> 
<div id="Superman" style="position:absolute;"></div>   
         
<style>   
#Superman { background: url(http://www.comixoasis.com/v/vspfiles/templates/runner/images/homepage/Superman.png) no-repeat; width:250px; height:300px; background-size: 100%;       
}  
</style>
    
</th>      
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.