# Move a Moving div, when hovering a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, mousehover

A (link) button fix in table cell (But link not working when clicked.)

How to move another 'Moving' div, when hovering the button?

Code:

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width='650' height='320' style="border: 1px solid #000; position: absolute; top: 300px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="Fly" style="position: absolute; left: 300px; top: -300px;">
                <div id="Superman"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 80px; top: 60px;">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909457/moving-div-moving-whole-page"></a>

            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#Superman {
    background: url(http://www.comixoasis.com/v/vspfiles/templates/runner/images/homepage/Superman.png) no-repeat;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background-size: 90%;
    transition: 3s ease;
}
#Superman:hover {
    background: url(http://www.mc-villalobos.com/sources/superman.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    transform: translate(0, 350px);
    /*move-down*/
}
.button {
    background: url(http://iconbug.com/data/26/256/a2ccff2488d35d8ebc6189ea693cb4a0.png) no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.button:hover {
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/__JNFVYfijS4/SX9bD7dk07I/AAAAAAAAAXw/VJCkHGqZFx4/s400/Happy.png) no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    function moveDown() {
        $('.Fly').animate({
            'marginTop': "+=100px"
        }, 1000, moveUp)
    }

    function moveUp() {
        $('.Fly').animate({
            'marginTop': "-=100px"
        }, 1000, moveDown)
    }
    moveUp();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/445/)

Comment: Please elaborate your question!! and ADD your code along!!!

Comment: I love how people think circumventing the no-jsfiddle link if no code block will roll well with us.

Comment: Please read the rules of posting questions.

Comment: Insert my link clinking hyperlink icon & save. The format look so weird...

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` element is empty:

```
<div class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 80px; top: 60px;">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909457/moving-div-moving-whole-page">
  </a>
</div>
```

Move the `div` inside it, and it should work:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909457/moving-div-moving-whole-page">
  <div class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 80px; top: 60px;">
  </div>   
</a>
```

Comment: Pasted now got hand icon (But link not working when clicked.) see http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/446/                                                                                         How to move another 'Moving' div, when hovering the button?